# Can one of my three-way switches be configured to use a remote control?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I want to put my outside flood lights on a remote control. They are controlled by two separate switches in two different rooms. One switch on the second floor and the other on the first floor. I want to change one of the switches to a remote control while leaving the other as a regular switch. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: What do you want the "remote control" to do?  There are a variety of wifi connected smart switches that seem to fit what you want.

Comment: Are you OK with the regular switch forever being a regular switch?

Answer (score 1):

### Make up your mind :)

One of the tropes around here is people wanting a light to be controlled by a complex switch scheme, *and also controlled by another complex switch scheme*.  Somehow, these are supposed to play nice together. **They don't**.  And it degrades into a glitchy mess pretty fast.

The best answer in this case is a networked smart-switch scheme that uses a programmable hub.  Now you can code in what each triggering action does.  This doesn't make it do what you want, but at least when it doesn't, you can improve the code to fix it.

And as far as products, you can use a smorgasboard of remote controls made to work with that system, including, potentially, your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only familiar with low voltage outdoor lighting and for it look into getting a transformer rated for outdoor flood lights with a photo lens to detect day/night if you want hands off. They have screws which you connect the outdoor wires too. Be sure you check the watts you need by adding up all the light watts that it runs. It just needs a standard receptacle to plug into. Just do a search on your favorite shopping site for "smart outdoor flood light transformer" and you'll be able to get an idea of those which can also be controlled remotely.

Comment: How does this address a remote controlled switch (not a timer) ?